# How do I generate document excerpts using Sphinx and the Sphinx PHP API?

Tags: search, sphinx

I am trying to generate search excerpts from the full text of indexed documents.  I am using Sphinx V2.02.  My Sphinx indexes work fine and regular results are no problem.

I am loading the document off disk so I've set `load_files` to TRUE.  I've tried both the web path of the file and the direct Linux file path.

Here is my excerpt code:

```
$options = array( 'load_files' => TRUE );
$docs = array( /files/0/123/123.txt );
$words = 'gears';
$excerpts = $sphinxclient->BuildExcerpts( $docs, 'files', $words, $options );
```

Here is the [Sphinx Documentation for Generating Excerpts](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.2/api-func-buildexcerpts.html).

`BuildExcerpts` returns false every time, rather than returning excerpts.  What's happening?  Should I be executing this somehow at the same time as my regular query?  I've been executing `BuildExcerpts` on each document returned from the main query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to BuildExcertps above is correct.

The problem is that my 'files' index is distributed and the Sphinx `BuildExcerpts` call doesn't like that.  It seems that BuildExcerpts is really just referencing the config for that index, so you have to reference one of the actual indexes, rather than the distributed index in the BuildExcerpts() call.

For example:  I have my files index split into 5 shards, files_0, files_1, etc.  Using 'files' as my index breaks BuildExcerpts.  Using files_0 or any of my shards works fine.

```
$options = array( 'load_files' => TRUE );
$docs = array( /files/0/123/123.txt );
$words = 'gears';
$excerpts = $sphinxclient->BuildExcerpts( $docs, 'files_0', $words, $options );
```